# Broken connection with MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, wildfly, wildfly-11, mariadb-connect-engine, mariadb-connector-c

I have a Wildly server connected to MariaDB Server on the same machine.

For some reason I get this error from time to time:

```
20:38:51,536 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 20:38:51.535 [default task-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08
20:38:51,536 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 20:38:51.536 [default task-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - (conn=25) Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
20:38:51,549 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 20:38:51.548 [default task-1] ERROR o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
20:38:51,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
20:38:51,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:275)
20:38:51,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
20:38:51,550 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
```

In MariaDB log I get: `2019-03-06 20:27:51 25 [Warning] Aborted connection 25 to db: 'production_gateway' user: 'wildfly' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)`

Do you know what might be the issue and how to fix it?

POM file:

```
https://pastebin.com/HUNy0ULy
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

JPA configuration:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

JDBC driver:

```
mariadb-java-client-2.4.0.jar
```

MariaDB version:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Can you advice?

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your pom.xml and watch out if your driver's version is compatible for your DB version as well. Some they have to update the driver web the DB developer make some change.

Comment: Lastest version for both, so the error can come from something else.

Comment: Is it for all calls, just some or intermittent?